# Parent of the root view hierachy

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to access a parent up the view hierarchy and doing something like the following:

```
ViewParent p = view.getParent();  
while(p != null) {  
  if(some condition) {  
    break;
  }  
  p = p.getParent();
}
```

Now this works ok, but I started wondering, is there a chance that the root of the hierarchy won't have `null` as parent (e.g. self-referencing view) and that ends up an infinite loop?

Comment: AFAIK, that will not happen. You could safeguard against that by keeping track of the visited nodes and breaking your loop if you re-visit a node.

Comment: @CommonsWare: would a reference equality check work for the views seen or does it need to be `equals`?

Comment: Reference equality would be what you want.